# Having trouble to find the node in ubuntu 14.04 after installing

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04, nvm

I installed the NodeJS in Ubuntu 14.04 by `nvm` by following this site [Installing NodeJS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server)
Though I had the following problem as

```
nvm ls
    sbin
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/sbin/alias’: Permission denied
```

Then I found to resolve this as (from [NVM solution](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/433))

```
$ export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
$ echo $NVM_DIR
/home/roy/.nvm
```

Then It works fine.

Now the problem, I face is that if I restart or even open a new console, I can't find the `node` again.

```
roy@Croy:~$ node -version
The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:

 * node

 * nodejs-legacy

Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I have to follow those steps,

I do `nvm install 0.11.13` then it shows

```
v0.11.13 is already installed.
Now using node v0.11.13
```

How to come out from here ?

Answer (score 0):

That version of node is not activated automatically. Try adding following in your ~/.bashrc

```
nvm use 0.11.13
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
nvm install stable
nvm alias default stable

node -v
npm -v
```